# Python adds extra to crypt result

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

I'm trying to create an API with token to communicate between an Raspberry Pi and a Webserver. Right now i'm tring to generate an Token with Python.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os
import time
import datetime
import requests
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
BLOCK_SZ = 14

#!/usr/bin/python
salt = "123456789123" # Zorg dat de salt altijd even lang is! (12 Chars)
iv = "1234567891234567" # Zorg dat de salt altijd even lang is! (16 Chars)


currentDate = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
currentTime = time.strftime("%H%M")
PADDING = '{'
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
secret = salt + currentTime
cipher=AES.new(key=secret,mode=AES.MODE_CBC,IV=iv)
encode = currentDate
encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, encode)

print (encoded)
```

**The problem is that the output of the script an exta b' adds to every encoded string.. And on every end a '**

```
C:\Python36-32>python.exe encrypt.py
b'Qge6lbC+SulFgTk/7TZ0TKHUP0SFS8G+nd5un4iv9iI='

C:\Python36-32>python.exe encrypt.py
b'DTcotcaU98QkRxCzRR01hh4yqqyC92u4oAuf0bSrQZQ='
```

Hopefully someone can explain what went wrong.

**FIXED!**

I was able to fix it to decode it to utf-8 format.

```
sendtoken = encoded.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes, a bytes object will have a `b"` prefix when you print it. But is this actually a problem? If you're sending the data over a serial port, or something similar, then it doesn't really matter what the data looks like when you print it, because you won't be printing it.

Comment: Oh, i tought that this is plain text... I'm going to send it over the web. I did just check the function to send it over the web and it sends the b' with it. The way i send it: link = "api.php?token=".format(encoded)
f = requests.get(link)

print (f.text)

Comment: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3 Might give you a good crash course on the difference between bytes and strings.

Comment: Worked out! Thanks Tom!!

Answer (score 0):

You are running Python 3.6, which uses Unicode (UTF-8) for string literals. I expect that the `EncodeAES()` function returns an ASCII string, which Python is indicating is a bytestring rather than a Unicode string by prepending the `b` to the string literal it prints.

You could strip the `b` out of the output post-Python, or <s>you could `print(str(encoded))`, which should give you the same characters, since ASCII is valid UTF-8.</s>

**EDIT:**

What you need to do is decode the bytestring into UTF-8, as mentioned in the answer and in a comment above.  I was wrong about `str()` doing the conversion for you, you need to call `decode('UTF-8')` on the bytestring you wish to print. That converts the string into the internal UTF-8 representation, which then prints correctly.

Comment: Tried print(str(encoded)) but was not succesfull. Same output as before.